# Drag&Drop in the Organization Chart

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, google-visualization

Drag and Drop is available for many Highcharts, but not seen it in the organization Chart. First of all is there a possible way to drag and drop the taks to a different Person and make a "new Connection". And second of all is  it possible to Drag and Drop so it gets Right in the middle of 2 People and "concets" to both?
Thanks in Advance
Juli.w